# Exception occurs while executing maven command i.e. mvn install

Tags: java, maven

I installed Maven 3.2.5 and executed `mvn install` being in my project Directory.
It shows following error:

> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Remote host closed connection during handshake: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely behind some proxy which interferes with SSL communicating with Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse->preferences->Maven->User Settings->open File link and update username and password, also validate proxy setting are correct

```
  <proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  **<user..>xxxx</user..>
  <pass..>xxxx</pass...>**
```