# Dspace installation issue

Tags: java, maven, solr

During Dspace installation, the following error has occurred:

```
Failed to execute goal on project solr: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project org.dspace.modules:solr:war:5.1: Could not transfer 
artifacr orgapache.solr:war:4.10.2 from/to 
central<https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2>: GET request of: 
org/apache/solr/solr/4.10.2/solr-4.10.2.war from central failed:SSL 
peer shut down incorrectly-> [Help 1]
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Maven issue and not a DSpace issue. You are having problems connecting to the Central Maven repository to download the necessary dependencies.

It's possible you are behind a proxy as noted in this similar error message on Stack Overflow: [Exception occurs while executing maven command i.e. mvn install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852816/exception-occurs-while-executing-maven-command-i-e-mvn-install)

Most likely, you need to configure a proxy in Maven. Here are some resources which describe how to do that:

- https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Installing+DSpace#InstallingDSpace-ConfiguringaProxy
- https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html